# Versioning RESTful Services in Weblogic

Tags: java, rest, jersey, weblogic, soa

I have a question about RESTful web services versioning in Weblogic (recent versions, 12c for example):

- I am developing a SOA arquitecture with RESTful APIS using Java/Jersey 2.0 and Weblogic
- This APIs have to be versioned (using [Semantic Versioning](http://semver.org))
- SOME OF ITS VERSIONS have to be deployed at the same time. URL examples:
  https:host:port/api/v1.0 and https:host:port/api/v2.1 have to be deployed at the same time in the same server
- Both versions are implemented in diferent source codes, and finally, in different .war files

My questions are:

1. Is this possible to do with Weblogic?
2. What is the best way to do it?
3. Are my concepts wrong? Is this the right way to do this arquitecture?

Comment: Did you find the solution ?